# mysql query and php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a config.php file which contains the connection info and a php script that should send user data to the database. There are no parse errors but the database keeps showing 0 entries in table. Any suggestions?

config file:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com","a******94_admin","*********");
mysql_select_db("a******94_members");

?>
```

form script:

```
<?php

require('scripts/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $u_name = ($_POST['u_name']);
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `u_name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$u_name', '$email', '$password')");

} else {


} //end of first if/else statement
```

?>

Comment: Change to `PDO` and check for query result.

Comment: Check your datatype of each and add that into the description.

Comment: And don't forget to escape your values! [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). ps. And add `or die(mysql_error());`  at the back of your query. That way you can debug what error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of ` use ' and update to MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

from the manual "mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error." return that first to see whats happening. obviously the query isnt working. check spelling of attributes in table  names etc. It also seem like you are not checking if the connection is working here either. just echo it out and see if its returning False.

Comment: or better yet, use `or die(mysql_error())` (even though it's deprecated) ;)

Answer (score -1):

If the field id is numeric and auto increment, it shouldn't be null. Instead of null put just

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `u_name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('', '$u_name', '$email', '$password')");
```

Comment: Won't make any difference.

Comment: Yes it make a difference  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892577/passing-null-from-php-to-mysql-for-auto-increment